# Linux version number convention

Tags: linux-kernel, history

With the first version of Linux, is the correct version number 0.01 (as seen in Tanenbaum's OS book) or should the first version be written 0.0.1 including the dot?

Comment: The version number would be whatever Torvalds wrote at the time; Tanenbaum may have quoted that (if not, the former applies).

Comment: It would be useful to mention to which of Tanenbaum's books you are referring - he wrote rather a lot!

Comment: Typically you'll have major.minor.patchlevel - although it can be a bit confusing before the first major release.  0.0.1 would've been the first patch of release 0.0 - ie. a patch to nothing (although C-programmers often start counting at 0 - eg. considering their 1st child as child number 0).   For pre-1.0 releases, it's common to jump version-numbers to show how close to the first release (1.0) you consider to be.  You may go from 0.2 (or 0.20) to 0.5... later to 0.95 to show you're close to release, and then to 0.99 (*very* close).  So 0.01 shows that Torvalds was just getting started...

Comment: There really is no "correct" version number. It is an arbitrary value created at the author's (or sometimes, their marketing people's) discretion... this is still true today in many places in practice (despite some efforts to formalize), and was especially true back then.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The correct version is “0.01”, as used in the tarball at the time ([available here](http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/Linux/kernel/Historic/)) and in the [release notes](http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/Linux/kernel/Historic/old-versions/RELNOTES-0.01).

Answer (score 15):

Let's do some archaeology. Torvald's 1991 paper, *LINUX--a free unix-386 kernel* (which you can read online [here](http://oldlinux.org/Linus/index.html)) discusses version 0.03 as can be seen in the list of files in the described FTP directory (emphasis mine):

> - linux-**0.03**.tar.Z--complete source to the operating system, in a 16-bit compressed tar archive.
>     [. . . ]
> - README, RELNOTES-**0.01**, INSTALLATION--ascii files containing some (somewhat out-of-date) information about LINUX.

Also note that it includes the release notes of the first version which is indeed referred to using `0.01`. Also, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel):

> By September 1991, version 0.01 of the Linux kernel was released on the FTP server (ftp.funet.fi) of the Finnish University and Research Network (FUNET). It had 10,239 lines of code. In October 1991, version 0.02 of the Linux kernel was released.[[2](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.minix/msg/2194d253268b0a1b)]

This cites [a message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.os.minix/4995SivOl9o/GwqLJlPSlCEJ) by Torvalds posted in October 1991 to the [comp.os.minix](http://news:comp.os.minix) newsgroup which describes version `0.02`:

> As I mentioned a month(?) ago, I'm working on a free version of a
>   minix-lookalike for AT-386 computers.  It has finally reached the stage
>   where it's even usable (though may not be depending on what you want),
>   and I am willing to put out the sources for wider distribution.  It is
>   just version 0.02 (+1 (very small) patch already), but I've successfully
>   run bash/gcc/gnu-make/gnu-sed/compress etc under it.

Finally, the first version of the Kernel is apparently still available in its original home at http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/Linux/kernel/Historic/. The file you can download there is:

> linux-0.01.tar.gz

So, since we can still see a `0.01` file and have evidence that the second version was `0.02`, it seems pretty clear that the first version was indeed `0.01` and not `0.0.1`.